# RequestMappingTemplate in Cloudformation yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to deploy application to Amazon using stackery. And I need to specify string value for RequestMappingTemplate. But I cannot correctly write it. Here is a part of yaml for function configuration

```
  CreateArticleConfiguration:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::FunctionConfiguration
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Sub ${ApiId}
      Name: !Sub kp_${EnvironmentTagName}_createArticle
      DataSourceName: !GetAtt CourseGraphQLToFnCreateArticleDataSource.Name
      FunctionVersion: 2018-05-29
      RequestMappingTemplate: |-
        {
          "version" : "2018-05-29",
          "operation": "Invoke",
          "payload": $util.toJson($context.args.input)
        }
```

When I try to deploy it with stackery, it raises error

> Error: Failed to parse template: while parsing a block mapping   in
> "", line 1658, column 7:
> ApiId:
> ^ expected , but found ''   in "", line 1667, column 39:
> ... RequestMappingTemplate: "{/n  /"version/" : /"2018-05-29/",/n  / ...

Here is how RequestMappingTemplate was processed to aws-sam\build\template.yaml

> RequestMappingTemplate: "{/n  /"version/" : /"2018-05-29/",/n
> /"operation/"/   : /"Invoke/",/n  /"payload/":
> $util.toJson($context.args.input)/n}"

If I change double-quotes to single-quotes, template is deployed successfully, but in AWS Mapping template is incorrect

> {/n  'version' : '2018-05-29',/n  'operation': 'Invoke',/n/ /
> 'payload': $util.toJson($context.args.input)/n}

I've tried to escape double-quotes with /, but it did not help. Can somebody tell me how such templates should be described correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Template text should be stored in separate file and then you need to use it like this

```
CreateArticleConfiguration:
    Type: AWS::AppSync::FunctionConfiguration
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Sub ${ApiId}
      Name: !Sub kp_${EnvironmentTagName}_createArticle
      DataSourceName: !GetAtt CourseGraphQLToFnCreateArticleDataSource.Name
      FunctionVersion: 2018-05-29
      RequestMappingTemplateS3Location: **path-to-file**
```